# log4j2 evaluation of user-created Lookup plugins is inconsistent and does not work at all when used programmatically

Tags: log4j2

I'm observing some behaviour with log4j2 Plugins that I can only interpret as inconsistent.

I'm trying to write a plugin to be used with RollingFileAppender that will let me change the header of each rolled file. I've decided to use a Lookup plugin for this (call it dynamicheader). One additional complication is that the RollingFileAppender and its associated PatternLayout are created programatically. The problems I observe are detailed below, but in summary:

1. The header property of the PatternLayout is never evaluated: calling getHeader() on the PatternLayout always returns "${dynamicheader:key} instead of the value associated with the key. If I replace "${dynamicheader:key}" with "${sys:key}" the header IS evaluated and getHeader() returns whatever value I set for "key".
2. If I configure a FileAppender with my plugin in a *configuration file* ("${dynamicheader:key}", see below), calling getHeader() on the associated PatternLayout DOES return the value associated with the key, but it is only evaluated once. If I change the value(header) associated with a key, subsequent calls to getHeader() do not re-evaluate the header and return the original key. However if I use 2 $ when I define the PatternLayout ("$${dynamicheader:key}"), the header IS evaluated on every call to getHeader(). This isn't surprising since (I gather) it is the expected behaviour, but, if I again replace my plugin with the SystemPropertyLookup, I need only a single $ for the header to be evaluated on every call to getHeader().

My plugin, configuration file and unit test to demonstrate the behaviour follow:

Plugin

```
package my.custom.plugins;

@Plugin(name = "dynamicheader", category = StrLookup.CATEGORY)
public class DynamicHeader extends AbstractLookup {
  private static Map<String, String> headerByAppender = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

  @Override
  public String lookup(final LogEvent event, final String key) {
    return get(key);
  }

  public void put(String key, String val) {
    headerByAppender.put(key, val);
  }

  public String get(String key) {
    return headerByAppender.get(key);
  }
}
```

Note that my plugin is very very similar to the SystemPropertiesLookup plugin and I'd expect them to behave similarly.

Config:

```
Configuration:
    name: TestConfig
    packages: "my.custom.plugins"
    Appenders:
        File:
            name: FILE
            fileName: target/surefire-reports/unit-test.log
            append: false
            PatternLayout:
                Pattern: "%m%n%ex"
                header: ${dynamicheader:key2}
    Loggers:
        Root:
            AppenderRef:
                ref: FILE
```

Tests:

```
public void testMyPlugin1() {
  DynamicHeader dh = new DynamicHeader();
  dh.put("key1", "val1");
  PatternLayout pl = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                                  .withPattern("%m%n%ex")
                                  .withHeader("${dynamicheader:key1}")  // use my plugin here...
                                  .build();
  assertEquals("val1", pl.getHeader());  // <- this fails. pl.getHeader() always returns "${dynamicheader:key1}"
}

public void testSysPlugin1() {
    System.setProperty("key1", "val1");
    PatternLayout pl = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                                    .withPattern("%m%n%ex")
                                    .withHeader("${sys:key1}")  // use sys plugin here...
                                    .build();
    assertEquals("val1", pl.getHeader());  // <- this works.
}

public void testMyPlugin2() {
    DynamicHeader dh = new DynamicHeader();
    Layout l = ((LoggerContext)LogManager.getContect(false)).getConfiguration().getAppender("FILE").getLayout();

    dh.put("key2", "val2"); 
    assertEquals("val2", l.getHeader());  // <- this works.

    dh.put("key2", "val3");
    assertEquals("val3", l.getHeader());  // <- this fails. getHeader() returns "key2"
}
```

However, if I chanege the coinfiguration file from

```
header: ${dynamicheader:key2}
```

to

```
header: $${dynamicheader:key2}
```

the above test passes. In contrast, if I change

```
header: ${dynamicheader:key2}
```

to

```
header: ${sys:key2}
```

the equivalent test passes:

```
public void testSysPlugin2() {
    Layout l = ((LoggerContext)LogManager.getContect(false)).getConfiguration().getAppender("FILE").getLayout();

    System.setProperty("key2", "val2"); 
    assertEquals("val2", l.getHeader());  // <- this works.

    System.setProperty("key2", "val3");
    assertEquals("val3", l.getHeader());  // <- this also works.
}
```

My questions then are:

1. Why is My plugin never evaluated when the PatternLayout is created programmatically? Am I doing something wrong?
2. Why does the SystemPropertyLookup behave differently than an virtually identical user-authored lookup.

I'm using log4j2 v2.8.2.

Thanks in advance!